# Change Web's Work Week/First Day of Week Programmatically

Tags: 2013, development, regional-settings

In Site Settings > Regional Settings it is possible to define a working week:

[image: Sharepoint work week]

Is it possible to change the first day of the week with server-side code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access working weeks information by modifying regional settings on an SPWeb
By Powershell :

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://yourweb" 
$web.RegionalSettings.WorkDayStartHour = (8 * 60) #8h converted in minutes
$web.RegionalSettings.WorkDayEndHour= (20 * 60) #convert in minutes
```

you can access all properties of the SPWeb RegionalSettings `$web.RegionalSettings`

More info http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/change-regional-settings-time-zone-locale-in-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell.html

Same thing with C# code ;)

Regards,

Comment: The `RegionalSettings` class is the one I needed. Then the `FirstDayOfWeek` property. Thanks :)

Comment: YW ;)

Regards,

DiscoPlacid